# SF short story - The annual(?) power station trip

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A man hikes through an abandoned town to an industrial building. He sweats and slightly injures himself doing several tasks by hand that normally would require a forklift. He throws a switch and watches in accomplishment/marvel as the town has electricity again for 80+ seconds. This may be a personal best. Then he hikes away again.

The title of this short story is on the tip of my brain and it's really bugging me.  What is it?

Known incorrect guesses:

- Walter Miller - *A Canticle For Leibowitz*
- Ray Bradbury - *Powerhouse*

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: So... just to be clear, you already know what the answer is?

Comment: Hi Jon. Is this a story that you're trying to remember or are you just setting us a challenge to identify a story you know?

Comment: No, I do not know the answer.  Question edited to make that clear.

Comment: Ugh, I have read this one too.  Flipping through anthologies...

Comment: A late welcome to SFF.SE jonrock! You should visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question, so that it will be easier for others to find the book that you are searching for.

Comment: I probably reread it within the last 5 years, but I'm reasonably sure that "reread" is correct and I don't know how long ago the first time was.

Comment: I read this one a long time ago.  Feels like Bradbury or Simak, but I doubt it's either one of them.  I have a vague memory of the protagonist yelling something like "I made you live again!" and then watching while the battery runs out and the city shuts down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That would be ["Lucifer"](https://books.google.com/books?id=-7wtAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=lucifer%20zelazny&source=bl&ots=ZApKmAO7PN&sig=CBx73XhDmnH-BqY3m5JcjaNK9u8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimoLjxuM_UAhUDbj4KHSUYDiIQ6AEIYDAJ#v=onepage&q=lucifer%20zelazny&f=false) by Roger Zelazny, collected in "The Doors of His Face, The Lamps of His Mouth".

> "Do you hear that?" he called out, shaking his fist at
>   anything."Ninety three seconds! I made you live for ninety three
>   seconds!"
>
> Then he covered his face against the darkness and was silent.
>
> After a long while he descended the stairway, walked the belt, and
>   moved through the long hallway and out of the Building. As he headed
>   back toward the mountains he promised himself - again - that he would
>   never return.

Comment: That's a nice title. And it's available online.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Found it in Google Books, so I added a link.

Comment: [Expletive deleted] Google Books, the story is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v02n02_1964-06).

Comment: For those who prefer hard copy, there are [several alternatives](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58669) to the Zelazny collection *The Doors of His Face, the Lamps of His Mouth*.

Comment: Answer accepted!  Thanks!

Comment: Good job! Would not have guessed Zelazny!